# Single-channel serial communication

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, uart

I'm trying to communicate with a device which only uses a single wire at 9600 Baud. How can I use my Arduino UNOs RX/TX-Pins to recieve and transmit on that one wire?

Comment: Please edit your question to include part # and/or datasheet link for the device.  Presumably it uses some communications protocol which you have left us to guess at.

Comment: Connect the data wire to RX, and connect RX to TX through a a 10K resistor?

Comment: Maybe it only communicates one way?

Comment: A bus called OneWire exists and may be what you are looking for. Just guessing. And you need to connect the ground of the devices too. So you will end up with two wires.

Answer (score 3):

Bidirectional Asynchronous Serial schemes are not uncommon.  The famous ones, like RS485, utilize special line drivers and differential signalling, but for short distances you can accomplish something similar using the ability of most MCU's, including the Arduino's ATmega, to tristate the serial transmit pin.

Essentially, you would wire the shared line to both the receive and transmit pins, and when it is not the Arduino's "turn" to transmit, you would configure the Transmit pin as an *input* rather than as an output.

It's then up to a software protocol to make each node transmit at only the appropriate time.  Often a bus master can transmit essentially at whim, and subservient device(s) are only allowed to transmit in reply to specific queries from the master.  Of course the master should not transmit when it has just request a reply.

Also note that you cannot change the pin over to input mode when the last character is *loaded* into the UART, rather it has to stay in output mode until the last sent character has been clocked out onto the wire.

While putting a resistor between the transmit pin and the shared line could provide some theorectical safety against bus contention introduced by software errors, in practice the hardware will typically survive such conflicts during development, and having too large a resistor there may cause problems with signal quality.  If you are going to use a resistor, it should be sized for source termination of the line impedance, *not* for electrical protection.  You may also want a weaker pulling resistor to give the bus a known state when no one is driving it.  If this state matches the last driven one, the resistor won't have to overcome capacitance to "drive" the line, but rather merely "hold" it in the last driven position.

If you are using a device like the Uno which has only one hardware serial interface, you will have to decide if you are going to use the hardware interface at the cost of breaking the ability to use that to debug or upload sketches, or if you are going to use a software UART ("Software Serial" or its variants) on arbitrary digital pins.  If you do the later, it would be entirely possible to rework a library to receive and transmit on the *same* pin, rather than requiring two distinct ones.